# Image with id won't obey javascript changing its z-index (or only does right sometimes)

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

I basically have 5 banners, all placed on `z-index:-100` so they don't show at page load. To display the banners, I simply put them on `z-index:100`, so they are over all the stuff on the screen. The javaScript functions responsible for showing/hiding the banners mostly work, with the exception of the `phase_a_end` one, which does not hide once shown (or most of the time it does not).

Html for the 5 banners below, as well as the js functions responsible to show/hide the banner and the function which call the show_banner function.

Prior to using the z-index's to show/hide the banners, I would set them to `opacity:0` `onLoad` and make them fully opaque when they needed to show. Still, every banner would obey me except for that phase_a_end one... (#4 starting from top)

```html
    <!-- OPPONENT'S PHASE A OVER BANNER -->
<img draggable=false id='end_of_phase_a_banner' name='end_of_phase_a_banner' ondrop="check_drop(event,'banner');" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" src='graphs/board/done_with_phase_a.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:-100; left:31%; top:35.25%; width:45.24%; height:24.25%'>
    <!-- OPPONENT'S PHASE B OVER BANNER -->
<img draggable=false id='opponent_done_banner' name='opponent_done_banner' ondrop="check_drop(event,'banner');" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" src='graphs/board/opponent_done.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:-100; left:31%; top:35.25%; width:45.24%; height:24.25%'>
    <!-- BEGINING OF YOUR TURN BANNER -->
<img draggable=false id='your_turn_banner' name='your_turn_banner' ondrop="check_drop(event,'banner');" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" src='graphs/board/your_turn.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:-100; left:31%; top:35.25%; width:45.24%; height:24.25%'>
    <!-- YOUR PHASE A OVER BANNER -->
<img draggable=false id='phase_a_end' name='phase_a_end' ondrop="check_drop(event,'banner');" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" src='graphs/board/phase_a_end.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:-100; left:31%; top:35.25%; width:45.24%; height:24.25%'>
    <!-- Y0UR PHASE B OVER BANNER -->
<img draggable=false id='phase_b_end' name='phase_b_end' ondrop="check_drop(event,'banner');" ondragover="allowDrop(event);" src='graphs/board/phase_b_end.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:-100; left:31%; top:35.25%; width:45.24%; height:24.25%'>
```

```js
function show_banner(banner_name) {
    var banner = parent.document.getElementById(banner_name);
    banner.style.zIndex = 100;
    var hidebans = setTimeout(function(){hide_banner(banner_name);},2000);
}

function hide_banner(banner_name) {
    var banner = parent.document.getElementById(banner_name);
    banner.style.zIndex = -100;
}

function force_end_of_phase_a() {
    show_banner('phase_a_end');
    play_sound('end');
    var epa = setTimeout(function() {parent.document.forms.end_phase_a.submit();},2500);
}
```

No errors at all in the browser console.

EDIT : Come to think about it, the problem may arise from the function being called from a frame whose parent is different than expected, even though I did check all references to the scripts used (as the last line of last function will confirm (form submission), which executes through every time (so the parent in the scope of the bug is definitely the right one). If you want to see this in action, you will need access to daregame.net.

Comment: not a full answer, but you probably want to use a style of `display: none` instead of fiddling with z-index.

Comment: Would agree ^. Use a display, opacity or visibility. z-index is not indented for hiding/showing elements

Comment: @Pureferret; wrong mate; a positive z-index like I need and a display:none makes it so that elements under your banner will not be clickable/hooverable, etc... at least hidden does that... I may try that and come back to you on it...

Comment: EDIT : and now believe it or not (now that the code has updated in both my browser's caches or something), I have the same problem but with banner #2 id='opponent_done_banner'... definitely gonna try display:none...

Comment: Okay, tried your thing and I was wrong : display:none will do it right for the stuff that's under the not-displaying banners, unlike with hidden... HOWEVER BELIEVE IT OR NOT : 3rd solution, and still a banner shows and stays there for some reason...!!! (crying lol) http://daregame.net/media/trying_it_out.mp4

Comment: Mind you, the shortly-showing banner probably stays because its hiding function is cut from executing as the button's iframe's script is refreshed in initialize_turn() so it now displays "enemy turn". I wonder if any reading this can even figure out how I deal with this clientA-server + clientB-server = server-clientB server-clientA situation (using solely php mysql javascript html). Most humans have a hard time off of client-server-client

Comment: Okay you can close this topic as I solved everything and found out all opaicty, z-index and display attributes were working solutions... it was all a matter of timing and misplaced procedures in my code (that,s what double client-server does : makes it hard not to forget a few things on the way and to re-read your code in the same pattern it,s executed... I'm running on an +40 IQ buff I won't name, 24hrs/day... and it's already not measurable through normal tests hehehey

Comment: @Phrank I don't follow your question fully, but it would be ***awesome*** if you posted an [answer] that showed how you fixed this.